# How can ı detec lines in this masked image?

Tags: python, image-processing

As you can see in the picture, I have a masked result. I want to find the linear lines in the masked area on this image. How can I do this? I am using Python while developing the project.[image]

Comment: check what value the background is and but a threshold slighly above it. this will segment the background as 0 and the rest as 1

Comment: this is not data, this is a colormapped visualization. please work on data, not on colormapped visualizations.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  Actually I am working on data. We got this picture after applying many operations to the picture.
I'm talking about the picture I shared as an example.

Comment: @Kubilay you can try Sembei's suggestion and later skeletonize the result